# How long do I need to wait after writing an object to appengine datastore can I read it?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an entity that I am writing to datastore as follows:

```
new_entity = ModelOb()
new_entity.interesting = True
new_entity_key = new_entity.put()
new_entity_key_urlsafe = new_entity_key.urlsafe()
```

I want to call the entity shortly afterwards. I have found that to call it using a query e.g.

```
the_entity = ModelOb.query().filter(ModelOb.interesting = True).get()
```

I need to wait a while (a few seconds) after the initial write otherwise it returns null. My question is if I use

```
the_entity = ndb.Key(urlsafe = new_entity_key_urlsafe).get()
```

is the time I'll need to wait less?

Comment: Try and find out I'd say

Comment: I've found a huge amount of discrepancy in my own tests which is why I'm asking here :/ Hoping for some insight from someone on the inside...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you retrieve the entity with the key, then you don't have to wait at all.  You can do it immediately after you put the entity.

If you retrieve the entity with a query, then you need to wait a bit. A few seconds is usually enough but there is no time limit after which you are guaranteed to be able to retrieve the object.  No matter how long you wait, there is always a possibility that the entity is not available, but that possibility is REALLY small after a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to extend this question slightly. If it is an existing entity and a specific property is updated e.g. new_entity.interesting = False in the example above. Could you give me a steer on how long I'd have to wait after the put() until I could read the object and see the change? This too seems to vary quite wildly for no reason that's apparent to me.

Comment: It is the same thing for updating an entity.  The key will always get you the latest update and with a query you'll need to wait a bit.

Comment: there are sometimes incidents (that affect large groups of apps at once) in datastore that cause that wait time to increase a lot. do not rely on waiting a few seconds ever. when those incidents happen many apps break because they have errors in their datastore handling about this.

Comment: In the SDK, the wait is set to 1 second. In the live environment it is typically less than that but, as mentioned, you should never rely on that for anything important.

Comment: Relying on a  second or so, is not a good design.  Ancestor queries will be up to date as well as get.  In fact once a get has been performed you will find you can immediately query.  However think about your design.  If you have just put the object, why are you querying for it.